# is it possible to use sed command to replace: ( -> \( meanwhile \( -> (

Tags: sed

the question is described in its title;
any idea to use `sed` command to replace text following below rules:

- `(` to `\(`
- `\(` to `(`

if there is no `|` in text, I can do 3 `sed`: 1. `(` -> `|(` 2. `\(` -> `(` 3. `|(` -> `\(`

but if we cannot grantee which character does not appear in the text, how to archive this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can try is, first replace `\(` with some invisible character, for example `\x99`, then do the `(` substitution, finally, change the `\x99`s.

### Example:

```
kent$  cat f
( ( ( \( \( \(

kent$  sed 's/[\](/\x99/g;s/(/\\(/g;s/\x99/(/g' f
\( \( \( ( ( (
```

Comment: The one character you know for sure will not be present (unless you have amended the line and put it there yourself!) is a newline. So `\x0a` is always the best *invisible character* to choose. in GNU sed you can use `\n` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with `perl`, you can use hash to save the mappings and use the matched portion as key in replacement section

```
$ echo '(1) \(2\) (3) \(4\)' | 
    perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $h{"("}="\\("; $h{"\\("}="(" } s/\(|\\\(/$h{$&}/g'
\(1) (2\) \(3) (4\)
```